# Modify a mysql record from PDO query results using php submit button

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

I have a php page that displays the results of a query. I want to have the ability to change a particular column from that results page.

```
echo "<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First</th>
    <th>Last</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Reason</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Update</th>
  </tr>";

// displaying data from database mysql using foreach loop

foreach ($pdoResult as $row)
{  
  echo"<tr>
    <td><p>$row[1]</p></td>
    <td><p>$row[2]</p></td>
    <td><p>$row[4]</p></td>
    <td><p>$row[5]</p></td>
    <td>
      <form action='update.php' method = 'post'>
        <select name='$row[0]'>
          <option name= 'status' value='$row[6]'>$row[6]</option>
          <option name= 'status' value='seen Benson'>seen Benson</option>
          <option name= 'status' value='seen cooper'>seen Cooper</option>
          <option name= 'status' value='seen Sheen'>seen Sheen</option>
          <option name= 'status' value='seen Wilks'>seen Wilks</option>
          <option name= 'status' value='not seen'>not seen</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='submit' name='$row[0]' value='update'>
      </form> 
    </td>
  </tr>";   
}
echo "</table>";
```

The update submit button doesn't work.

How do I code the submit button to recognize the unique ID for the particular queried result then change the "Status" and update it in the mysql database?

Comment: What do you mean by "The update submit button doesn't work"? And why are you naming both your `<select>` and your `<input>` the same thing?

Comment: You don't show your update code at all, so it's hard to tell where it's going wrong.

Comment: Plus,  `<form>` cannot be child of `<table>`, so that should be fixed.

Comment: There's also no php/mysql to support the question.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

[check this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9dZrzyA-1rCUUt2ZlpZVUhIV1U) i think you want to use unique id to show the specific row in you text or input field and than want to update them in the database. here i just gave you the normal id example.
if you want to add unique id to show the result and update them than you have to modify the id to uni:

```
class user{
public uid='';
public function __construct($data=''){
if(array_key_exist('uid',$data)){
this->uid=$data['uid'];
}
}

public function update(){

    try {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'root', '');
        $query = "UPDATE `users` SET user_name = :u_name WHERE uid="."'".$this->uid."'";

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array(

            ':u_name' => $this->user_name

        ));

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Here after the"...uid=" i have written

```
$query = "UPDATE `users` SET user_name = :name WHERE uid="."'".$this->uid."'";
```

because i set the type of uid in varchar so that i keep this  like ("'".$this->uid."'")  this. So i hope so you get your answer and try this and give a feedback. Thank You.